# C add hex-value to string, no library

Tags: c, arrays, string, addition

I have a function that requires to send a string with `<cr>` at the end. How can I directly
join the string-part with the `<cr>` = 0x0D in C without using any library function? (I am using uC.)

Example array/string "ABC\x0D", but 0x0D should be not sent as ascii but as `<cr>`.

Comment: Can you clarify on that?

Comment: Need to see your code. This cannot work, for example, if the initial string is a constant.

Comment: There are many ways to do it, but which works depends on context.  We'll need to see your code to know what can be done in this context.  Basically, you need to concatenate `"\r"` on the end of the string.  The library function `strcat()` does that; you can easily write your own version.  ***But*** if the string is a string literal, you'll need to make a copy first in enough space to allow for the CR too.  And regardless you need to have enough space for the extra byte of data.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear enough, lets say i have a function to send a command: send_command("ABC") then the command ABC should be sent with a <cr> added at the end in some cases. Basically all i want is to somhow add the <cr> within the string that i give to the send_command function. Since i work on a very limited microcontroller no functions like strcat()... are available.

Comment: @user3482407 If I understand you correctly, `"ABC\x0D"` or `"ABC\r"` will do what you want.

Comment: Will every invocation of `send_command()` require the CR at the end?  If so, the code to change is in `send_command()`.  If not, then you've either got to modify the calling code to pass `"ABC\r"` instead of `"ABC"`, or you need to change the relevant calls to call a new function, `send_command_cr("ABC")` where the called function adds the CR.  We can't tell which is most appropriate; we don't have your code.  On the whole, changing the string literal to add the CR is likely to be the best solution.

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler wrote, with `"ABC\r"`. You seem confused about ASCII values. `\0x0D` and `\r` and (somehow) `<cr>` are all the same ASCII value 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have enough room in your array, you simply put at the end of the string a `0x0d` and a `\0`. Example :

```
char str[8] = "ABCDEF";
```

This string contains 6 characters and the terminating null : it can accept the cr. How to do that :

```
str[6] = '\r'; /* or 0x0d or 13 */
str[7] = '\0'; /* or 0x0 or 0 */
```

That's all...